# Division in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function subtraction(num1, num2){       
    var num3; 
    num3 = num1 - num2;
    document.writeln("Difference "+ num3);
    return (num3);
}    

function division(num1, num2){
    difference = parseFloat(subtraction());
    var x;
    while(difference > 0){
        difference = num1-num2;
        x = x + 1;
    }
    document.writeln("Quotient" + x);
}
```

Hi! I wanted to do a division function but the catch is I will not use "/". This is what I got and so far this prints out "undefined" and if I stated x = 0 it will print out "0".

Comment: Integer division? Or what? Please add the relevant details.

Comment: What does `subtraction()` do with no arguments?

Comment: If "num1" is greater than "num2" then the loop will never terminate.

Comment: Why do you want/need to do this? This could be an impressive case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: Please post the code to `subtraction`. Also, beware of negative numbers. If `num2 <= 0`, your `while` loop will run forever.

Comment: I know you stated this before but `var x` will need to be initialized to a beginning value.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP It's an assignment and I'm stuck

Comment: @DesertIvy There you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed some problems with your code:

```
function division(num1, num2){
        var difference = num1-num2; // difference is now a local variable

        var x = 0;  // x should be initialized
        while(difference > 0){
            difference = difference-num2; // difference should change, not always be num1-num2
            x = x + 1;
        }
        console.log("Quotient" + x);
        console.log("Remainder" + (difference+num2));
   }
```

http://jsbin.com/UQIqejo/1/edit

You still have some problems with the algorithm itself, as num2 being less than or equal to 0 will result in an infinite loop, but i expect finding those problems is part of the fun.

**EDIT:** Smaller version of the same code:

```
 function divisionSmall(a,b) {
      var x = 0;
      while ((a-=b) > 0) x++;
      console.log('Quotient', x);
      console.log('Remainder', a+b);
    }
```

**EDIT2:** Correct division:

```
function divisionSmall(a,b) {
  var x = 0;
  while ((a-=b) > 0) x++;  
  return [x, a+b];
}

function divisionCorrect(a,b) {
  var ans;
  if (b === 0) return ['INF', 0];  


  if ((a > 0) && (b > 0)) {
    return divisionSmall(a,b);
  }

  if ((a > 0) && (b < 0)) {
    ans = divisionSmall(a,-b);
    return [-ans[0], ans[1]];
  }

  if ((a < 0) && (b > 0)) {
    ans = divisionSmall(-a,b);
    return [-ans[0] - 1, b-ans[1]];
  }


  if ((a < 0) && (b < 0)) {
    ans = divisionSmall(-a,-b);
    return [ans[0] + 1, -b-ans[1]];
  }
}

console.log(divisionCorrect(11,3));   //  3, 2
console.log(divisionCorrect(11,-3));  // -3, 2
console.log(divisionCorrect(-11,3));  // -4, 1
console.log(divisionCorrect(-11,-3)); //  4, 1
```

There is still the challenge of doing the logic without `if`s :). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If your doing numbers their is a  simpler way to do this using recursion:

```
function divide(num,denom) {
  if (num < denom) return 0;
  return (1 + divide(num - denom, denom));
}
```

For negative numbers you would have to extend this to track if numbers were less than 0. Also, while concise and neat, this breaks down for large numerators and small denominators as the max call stack size will be exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with your while loop. If the `subtraction` method returns a negative number it will not compute.

User `Math.abs` to get absolute value.

```
   <script>
   function division(num1, num2){
        var difference = Math.abs(parseFloat(subtraction(num1, num2)));
        var x = 0;
        while(difference > 0){
            difference = difference-num2;
            x = x + 1;
        }
        document.writeln("Quotient" + x);
   }
   function subtraction(num1, num2){ 
      var num3; 
      num3 = num1 - num2; 
      document.writeln("Difference "+ num3); return (num3); 
   }
   </script>
```